# Overriding a selector callback with different functionality

Tags: jquery

I have a set of inputs:

```
<input class="test"></input>
<input class="test"></input>
<input class="test"></input>
<input id="diff" class="test"></input>
```

and some jQuery to do stuff when the user clicks these inputs:

```
$(function () {
    $(".test").on("click", function () {
        alert("test");
    });
    $("#diff").on("click", function () {
        alert("diff");
    });
});
```

Currently the 4th text box will  show two alerts.  How do I 'override' the default alert saying "test" to just say "diff"?

Many thanks.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G3PAy/

Many thanks.

Comment: in the .test click function: if($(this).attr('id') != 'diff') {alert("test");}

Comment: @dmoss18: That would work, but it seems like it would be more fragile than using the .is() functionality in jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to specify the priority of different handlers, so you need to exclude it explicitly in the first click handler:

```
$(".test:not(#diff)").on("click", function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

The second click handler (for `#diff`) stays as it is.

Comment: This works so long as that format of CSS selector is supported by the browser.  I think jQuery will make sure those selectors work even on old browsers, right?

Comment: jQuery has its own selector processor, it's not dependent on the browser.

Comment: This will never 'just say "diff"' as the OP asked. In fact, this is less functional than the code they already had.

Comment: Clarified that he shouldn't remove the handler for `#diff`. I thought it was obvious.

Answer (score 1):

It strikes me that you may be going about this the wrong way.

I would first think you should attempt to engineer your tags such that the #diff tag does not have the same class.  One way would be to apply the same CSS rules to a new class as so:

```
.test
{
/* CSS rules */
}
```

becomes

```
.text, .newClass
{
/* new CSS rules */
}
```

If, however, you don't want to do that, you can test against other properties in your jQuery.

You can use the following code to achieve the result you want:

```
$(function () {
    $(".test").on("click", function () {
        if( !$(this).is("#diff"){
        alert("test");
        }
    });
    $("#diff").on("click", function () {
        alert("diff");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to do this, depending on the logical specifics of what you're trying to achieve.

I opted to interpret it as follows:

1. Whenever an input is clicked, run a test
2. If it's a `#diff`, alert us of it, OR
3. If it's a `.test`, alert us as to that

So effectively, there are a series of tests, and some conditions override the others. To do this, you run a general selector with jQuery, then use an else if logical statement to determine the course of action.

Modified code here:

```
$(function () {
    $("input").on("click", function () {
        if($(this).is('#diff')){
            alert("diff");
        }
        else if($(this).is('.test')){
            alert("test");
        }
    });
});
```

Demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/barney/QkrbK/

Comment: This works for the given inputs, true, but it seemed to me that the question was more about how to apply something to one class and exclude specific elements which met another criteria.  This would have unneeded jQuery running for each input click.

Comment: My original thought was to test for `.test, #diff` as a selector, when I realised that the question started "I have a set of inputs". I figured separating the acceptance criteria from the conditional statement would be a good way of disambiguating the logical challenge. All in all though, jQuery selectors are perhaps the easiest thing to get to grips with — I doubt interpreting pr changing them will be too problematic.

Answer (score 1):

Try inline click event with **[event.stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)**

```
<input id="diff" class="test" onclick="show();event.stopImmediatePropagation();"></input>
```

And

```
function show() {
    alert("diff");
}
```

See [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/G3PAy/2/)

Comment: This could have unintended consequences if there's anything else that should be run, but is otherwise functional.